# History.js Issue

Tags: javascript, html, history.js

I got my history API to work however I am trying to implement History.js but I can't seem to access the state.data. I want to use the string in the state.data to9 call the corresponding function. While my concept works well for the History API it doesn't for History.js my code is located below:

```
(function (window, undefined) {
    var History = window.History; // Note: We are using a capital H instead of a lower h
    if (!History.enabled) {
        // History.js is disabled for this browser.
        // This is because we can optionally choose to support HTML4 browsers or not.
        return false;
    }

    // Bind to StateChange Event
    History.Adapter.bind(window, 'statechange', function () { // Note: We are using statechange instead of popstate
        var State = History.getState(); // Note: We are using History.getState() instead of event.state
        alert(State.data);
        if (State.data != null) {
            var strFun = State.data;
            alert(strFun);
            //Create the function call from function name and parameter.
            var mySplitResult = strFun.split(",");
            //var strParam = "null";
            //Call the function and arguments 
            window[mySplitResult[0]](mySplitResult[1], mySplitResult[2]);
        }
    });
})(window);
```

My links are as such:

```
<li>
  <a href="#" onclick="javascript:History.pushState({state:newarticles},'New Articles','newarticle'); return false;">Articles</a>
</li>
<li>
  <a href="#" onclick="javascript:History.pushState({state:displaybookmarks},'Favourties','favourties'); return false;">Favourites</a>
</li>
<li>
  <a href="#" onclick="javascript:History.pushState({state:pagenation},Listing,1,'Archive','archieve1'); return false;">Archive</a>
</li>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to call each is the following...  Notice that the onclick doesn't have the javascript:, and the state data is quoted!

```
<a href="#" onclick="History.pushState({state:'newarticles'},'New Articles','newarticle'); return false;"&gt;Articles&lt;/a>
```

Hope that helps!
PEte

Comment: will give it a try and document my results

Comment: ok this still doesn't work when I alert my state.data i get Object Object and not a string. How can I get my state.data to show a string instead of an object.

Comment: i got this to work but with the state.title instead of the state.data. It seems state.data is still holding an object for some reason

Comment: It's pushing the state into an object because you're pushing it in as an object.  Instead of doing .pushSate({state:'newarticles'}, "new"...) Try just doing .pushState("newarticles", "New Articles"...

Comment: I tried that already and it didn't work actually it worked fine in the normal History API for HTML5 but not for History.js